# Centering a receipt title with CPCL Programming(Zebra mobile Printeres)?

Tags: c#, printing, zebra-printers

I am producing a receipt with my c# and CPCL code. I've got company name on the top of the receipt.Company name is setup according to who is using that software, I want be able to center that company name. I have tried with command CENTER but its not doing anything I dont know If I am doing something wrong.

My Code is:

```
SendData = " ! U1 setvar \"device.languages\" \"line_print\"\r\n";
SendData += " ! U SETLP 5 1 46\r\nPAGE-WIDTH 480\r\nSETBOLD 2\r\nPRINT\r\n";          
SendData += " ! U1 CENTER\r\n"+MobileOrdering.AppSettings.Company+"\r\n! U1 SETBOLD 0\r\n";
SendData += " ! U1 CENTER\r\n";
SendData += " ! U1 SETLP 0 2 24";
SendData += MobileOrdering.AppSettings.Address+"\r\n";
```

Pls help

Comment: whats wrong with center command? can you show cpcl code?

Comment: @Reniuz I've added my cpcl code, its just not centering, looks like its ignoring center command or I am doing completely wrong

Answer (score 1):

Well as I understood correctly after reading a bit of [this](http://www.ptshome.com/kb/Manuals/CPCL.pdf) manual, you using in line print mode so you can justify just bar codes not text.

(from P9-15)

> The BARCODE command is affected by the justification
>   commands like “! U1 CENTER”.

(from P9-18)

> The program must set up the file with all the spacing
>   already inserted.  Use only spaces, not tab characters, to
>   make things line up correctly

to test if I'am correct try instead of company name add bar code, if it will be centered - I'am right :)

To add centered text you can also try just use commands in label mode:

```
! 0 200 200 210 1
CENTER
TEXT 4 3 0 0 Centered Company Name
LEFT
TEXT 4 3 0 0 Text on left
FORM
PRINT
```

Hope that helps.