# Centering a receipt title using cpcl language (Zebra Printers & Android)

Tags: java, android, zebra-printers

my android code to send the command to Zebra Printer looks like this actually but doesn't place text in the center of the receipt

```
      String sendCommand = "! U1 SETLP 5 4 46\n" +
                            Hello World !+
                            "! U1 CENTER\n"));
```

This answer didn't help me either
  [Centering a receipt title with CPCL Programming(Zebra mobile Printeres)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7158308/centering-a-receipt-title-with-cpcl-programmingzebra-mobile-printeres)

Comment: It's difficult to tell what's being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be answered in its current form. For help clarifying this question, see the [help] (especially [ask]).

Comment: It's clear now ?!

Answer (score 0):

As stated in your given reference ([Centering a receipt title with CPCL Programming(Zebra mobile Printeres)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7158308/centering-a-receipt-title-with-cpcl-programmingzebra-mobile-printeres)), the justication commands only works on "Line print" mode.

If you want to use the "CENTER" command you have to use the normal CPCL mode. You can check the information in the [tutorial](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/en-us/printer/cpcl-pm-en.pdf).

Here is an input example:

`! 0 200 200 210 1
CENTER 383
TEXT 4 0 0 75 C
LEFT
TEXT 4 0 0 75 L
RIGHT 383
TEXT 4 0 0 75 R
FORM
PRINT`